# ConnectException while Instrument Test on real device is running

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, ktor

I have a non-trivial issue. We made a back-end on Android device. For REST-Service using Ktor.
I'm trying to run an instrumental test like:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@Config(application = HiltTestApplication::class)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class RestServiceTest {
    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Inject
    lateinit var testServer: TestServer

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/askp/")
        .addConverterFactory(
            MoshiConverterFactory.create(
                Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
            )
        )
        .build()
    private val api = retrofit.create(SuvApi::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
            testServer.start()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun successTransactionsHistory() = runBlocking{
        delay(5000)
        val response = api.getTransactionHistory(1)
        Assert.assertNotNull(response)
    }
}
```

But when test function call it throws ConnectException ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused).
The test is running on real physical device and i establish connection like that in prodaction code and it works.

Comment: Could you please share the minimal dependencies for your test and implementations for the `SuvApi` and `TestServer` classes?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman sorry, silly mistake, server started on 8081 port, but i send requests on 8080